# Model kept deleting itself from 'Replicatedstorage' when i playtested it

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm trying to make these parts (as you can see they're called SilverBars, yes they are a breakables for a simulator game). I'm trying to make them spawn at random places in a specific box every 2 seconds, and it worked. But when I tried to loop it, that's where it started deleting the models.

I tried moving some functions, it just gives no output and does nothing. oh yeah and when I tried playtesting it before I started moving things up, this error message appeared 'SilverBars isn't a valid member of 'Replicatedstorage'.

```
function RandomSilver()

    game.ReplicatedStorage.SilverBars:Clone()

    game.ReplicatedStorage.SilverBars.Parent = workspace

    wait(2)

    game.Workspace.SilverBars.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-22.8, 23.2), 12.1, math.random(18.2, 152.1))

end

while true do

    RandomSilver

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are cloning "SilverBars" then you change original "SilverBars" parent and then you wait 2 seconds and change original "SilverBars" position. You need to change cloned "SilverBars" parent and position not original one. So, you need to create variable of cloned silver bars than change parent and position of it.

Your model "deleting itself" from "ReplicatedStorage" because you are changing original "SilverBars" parent, and it is not deleting itself it actually moves to the "workspace"

```
function RandomSilver()

    local clonnedSilverBars = game.ReplicatedStorage.SilverBars:Clone()

    clonnedSilverBars.Parent = workspace

    clonnedSilverBars.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-22.8, 23.2), 12.1, math.random(18.2, 152.1))

end
```

To call a function you need to put "()" after function name:

```
while true do

    RandomSilver() -- here

end
```

Also you need to call "RandomSilver" function every 2 seconds so:

```
while true do

    RandomSilver()

    wait(2)

end
```

And if you put it all together you will get:

```
function RandomSilver()

    local ClonedSilverBars = game.ReplicatedStorage.SilverBars:Clone()
    
    ClonedSilverBars.Parent = workspace

    ClonedSilverBars.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-22.8, 23.2), 12.1, math.random(18.2, 152.1))

end

while true do

    RandomSilver()
    
    wait(2)

end
```

It will work only if "SilverBars" is a part, if it's a model then you need to use "MoveTo" function so if you have a model use this code:

```
function RandomSilver()

    local ClonedSilverBars = game.ReplicatedStorage.SilverBars:Clone()

    ClonedSilverBars.Parent = workspace

    ClonedSilverBars:MoveTo(Vector3.new(math.random(-22.8, 23.2), 12.1, math.random(18.2, 152.1)))

end

while true do

    RandomSilver()

    wait(2)

end
```

**Answer to the comment:**

To add a limit, you need to add a folder in "workspace" and name it "SilverBarsFolder" then change this: `ClonedSilverBars.Parent = workspace` to this:

`ClonedSilverBars.Parent = workspace.SilverBarsFolder` to put cloned silver bars to "SilverBarsFolder".

In the while loop, you need to check if the number of children in the "SilverBarsFolder" folder (the number of silver bars) is less than the limit, if so, call the "RandomSilver" function:

```
function RandomSilver()

    local ClonedSilverBars = game.ReplicatedStorage.SilverBars:Clone()

    ClonedSilverBars.Parent = workspace.SilverBarsFolder

    ClonedSilverBars.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-22.8, 23.2), 12.1, math.random(18.2, 152.1))

end

while true do

    if (#workspace.SilverBarsFolder:GetChildren() < 10) then

        RandomSilver()

    end

    wait(2)

end
```

":GetChildren()" - gives you table with all objects in some object (in this case, folder).

"#" - gives you a number of objects in table.

Comment: pixelfire wow, thanks. anyways how do i set a limit? i cant seem to use the variable method of adding a value every 2 seconds since it always gives 'expected identifier when parsing expression got '+=' when i tried local limit += 1. this is just for optimisation.

Comment: Answer to your comment is in the edit.